# How to make an element stop triggering ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, slider

I'm making a content slider for my project but I have very little expirience in AngularJS.
I've found [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/I2vmyTxK2kN3slqCQxFV/preview) which suits my needs greatly. You can see my live [page here](http://returnx.ru/nojob/index.html). It is in russian language, but I hope it wont be a problem. Slider is in the middle of the page - a section with 8 cards.

So the problem is:
Slider is controlled by the arrows below it. Still if you click on the red button inside the card it will update the model and classes ng-enter and ng-leave will be applied to the parent container which will result in slider animation. Well, the problem becomes obvious if you just click these red buttons.

Is there any way to make these red buttons not apply ng-enter and ng-leave classes to the container div?

UPDATE: [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTHuEhYs4VUImBbOWG6X?p=preview), that illustrates my problem. The animation must happen when you click on Prev and Next buttons. But it happens when you click on "Choose" or "Choosen" links, which updates the model.

This is a markup

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="gift-page" ng-class="direction" ng-repeat="page in gifts | partition: 6 | offset: currentPage | limitTo: 1">
          <ul class="gift-list clearfix">
              <li class="gift" ng-repeat="gift in page">
                  <div class="gift-item">
                      <div class="gift-details">
                          <h3>{{gift.title}}</h3>
                          <span class="points">{{gift.points}} points</span>
                          <a href="" class="buy" ng-show="!gift.ordered" ng-click="addToBasket(gift)">Choose</a>
                          <a href="" class="bought" ng-show="gift.ordered" ng-click="removeFromBasket(gift)">Chosen</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button ng-click="prev()">Prev</button>
      <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Could you create some plunk to have possibility play with it? I have idea with $animate.enabled(false), but this solution is not recommended..

Comment: [Here is plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTHuEhYs4VUImBbOWG6X?p=preview). It is almost the same as a problem on my page. The animation should happen only when you click buttons Next and Prev (which doesnt happen) and not when you click on "Choose" or "Choosen" links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick, but **not the best solution** is to turn off animation before action and turn on after:

```
  $scope.addToBasket = function(gift){

    $animate.enabled(false);

    gift.ordered = true;

    $timeout(function(){
      $animate.enabled(true);
    })
  }
```

Here is [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IKoMm062DiZ5hDTaV8d7?p=preview).
Will look for better solution later))

Comment: Thank you so much. I got stuck here for 3 days with no idea how to solve. At least it works now!

Comment: The real problem is in pagination. This pagination is made in such way that any change in original collection (gifts) will lead to recalculating page and animation will be applied as well. I recomend you to rewrite it in convenient way.

Comment: The problem with quick solution is that it is not recomended to turn off/on animation manually and also avoid usage of timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Can try adding $event.stopPropagation(); to the ng-click event, in your case:

```
<a href="" class="buy" ng-show="!gift.ordered" ng-click="addToBasket(gift); $event.stopPropagation();">Выбрать</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt help.